# WCF-Rest security using Windows Identity Foundation (STS)

Tags: ajax, wcf, wif, wcf-rest

I have successfully installed a “Security Service Token”.

I have a Wcf-Rest service that is running under the STS created as security. 
I am calling the Wcf-Rest service from a Web page using ajax. I would like get the Claims that I have received in the web page once successfully log-in in the STS. 
I am able to pass the encrypted cookie, but the wcf-rest service cannot read any claim.
Does Wcf-rest (webHttpBinding) support this possibility?

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of plumbing - yes.

[Securing WCF Data Services using WIF](http://www.leastprivilege.com/SecuringWCFDataServicesUsingWIF.aspx)

Also see [Claims Based Identity & Access Control Guide](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/)  which has some chapters on REST.

Comment: Hey i've read through the links you provided an still can't figure out how i can re-use the issued claims from javascript for a WCF REST service. If you have more pointers, those would be appreciated.